# Android Kotlin registerForActivityResult no callback

Tags: android, kotlin

In Android 13, I need a basic flow to get permission for push notifications:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(), LocationListener {
    val notificationPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()) { isGranted: Boolean ->
        if (isGranted) {
            // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
            // app.
        } else {
            // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
            // feature requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
            // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
            // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
            // decision.
        }
    }

    private fun requestPushNotificationPermissions(){
        if ((ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
            // granted
        }else {
            // not granted, ask for permission
            notificationPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
        }
    }
}
```

This is what happened:

- when user first installed the app, checkSelfPermission returns not granted, and we then lauch permission launcher
- user sees the permission dialog in Android 13
- user selects Allow
- Expected: registerForActivityResult callback will be fired with isGranted true
- Actual: registerForActivityResult callback is not fired.

Same if user selects Not Allow. callback is never fired. Why?

This is my dependencies:

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.0-alpha07'
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.0-alpha07'
```

Comment: Your code looking fine so it should work but still would like to suggest that use stable version instead of alpha so can you just change from alpha to stable versions and try again ?
and also just check manifest that it contains ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, the registerForActivityResult callback never fires, because somewhere in the Activity, there is this piece of old function "onRequestPermissionsResult" that is accidentally catching all permissions callback:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {        
    if (requestCode == locationPermissionCode) {
        if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //Location permission granted
        }
        else {
            //Location permission denied
        }
    }else{
        //Notification permission callback accidentally landed here silently        
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

sadly can't help why it doesn't work. But I used EasyPermission for handling the permissons request and it works fine.
https://github.com/googlesamples/easypermissions